# What two different keys go to the same reducer by the default hash partitioner in Hadoop?

Tags: java, hadoop, hadoop-partitioning

As we know that `Hadoop` guarantees that the same keys which come from different `mappers` will be sent to the same `reducer`.

But if **two different keys have the same hash value**, they definitely will go to **the same** `reducer`, so will them be sent to **the same** `reduce` method **orderly**? Which part is responsible for this logic?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q1:`so will them be sent to the same reduce method orderly`

Ans : yes

---

Q2:`Which part is responsible for this logic`

Ans : [shuffle sort](https://www.inkling.com/read/hadoop-definitive-guide-tom-white-3rd/chapter-6/shuffle-and-sort)

---

Example :

```
key  value
 1       2
 1       2
 2       5
 3       19
 6       20
```

Lets say number of reducer is 5 
so now .

```
Reduce 0 will get key NO key-value pairs
Reduce 1 will get key 1,6 in same order 
Reduce 2 will get key 2
Reduce 3 will get key 3
Reduce 4 will get key NO key-value pairs
```

Comment: So the reduce method will be invoked twice, with parameters <1,[2,2]> and <6,[20]> seperately?

Comment: Yes.Reduce method will get only one key at a time .